# Disabling 'paste' in a jTextfield

Tags: java, swing, awt, jtextfield

I have an app that is written in Swing, awt.
I want to prevent users from pasting values into the textfields.
is there any way to do this without using action listeners?

Answer (score 23):

You can just call setTransferHandler with a null parameter like this:

```
textComponent.setTransferHandler(null);
```

This will disable all copy/paste actions on the field.

Comment: Thanks, in my case I need to enable the paste of an image file or print screen.

Answer (score 5):

The best way is to remove action associated with CTRL+V keystroke in components ActionMap.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way it to say: `textComponent.setEditable(false);`

This disables cut & paste, but copy is still enabled.

Comment: True story, I have a text component where isEditable() returns false, but TransferAction still lets you paste into it.  Pressing Ctrl-V is disabled, but if you have a Paste action in the main menu which is hooked up to the relevant component's transfer action, people will still be able to paste.

Comment: @Trejkaz hmm .. haven't seen such misbehaviour since ages (early swing versions did), and can't reproduce it right now.

Comment: Might have been fixed in the past few months.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class PastlessJTextField extends JTextField {

        public PastlessJTextField() {
            super();
        }
        public PastlessJTextField( int columns ){
            super( columns );
        }

        @Override
        public void paste() {
            // do nothing
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to override the `paste()` method in `JTextComponent`.